# Understanding QT's graphics view coordinate system

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code:

```
QGraphicsScene* pScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(pScene);
pScene->addRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
QGraphicsRectItem* pRect1 = pScene->addRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
QGraphicsRectItem* pRect2 = new QGraphicsRectItem(20, 20, 19, 19, pRect1);
QPointF pf1 = pRect1->pos();
QPointF pf2 = pRect2->pos();
QPointF pf3 = pRect2->mapFromParent(pRect1->pos());
QPointF pf4 = pRect2->mapToParent(pRect2->pos());
QPointF spf1 = pRect1->scenePos();
QPointF spf2 = pRect2->scenePos();
```

Nothing special, just a QGraphicsView with QGraphicsScene and a few QGraphicsRectItem(s).
**Question:** Why do all the points (pf1, pf2, pf3, pf4 and even spf1, spf2) equal QPointF(0.0, 0.0) after execution?

I'm using Qt 5.4.1.

From my understanding spf1 must be QPointF(40.0, 40.0) and spf2 must be QPointF(20.0, 20.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look in the documentation then you will find:

> QGraphicsRectItem *QGraphicsScene::addRect(const QRectF &rect, const
>   QPen &pen = QPen(), const QBrush &brush = QBrush())
>
> Creates and adds a rectangle item to the scene, and returns the item
>   pointer. The geometry of the rectangle is defined by rect, and its pen
>   and brush are initialized to pen and brush. **Note that the item's
>   geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is
>   initialized to (0, 0). For example, if a QRect(50, 50, 100, 100) is
>   added, its top-left corner will be at (50, 50) relative to the origin
>   in the items coordinate system**

.As result, the coordinate of the Item is (0,0) but you can set it with:

```
pRect1->setPos(QPoint(30,30));
```

and look what will happen. Hope it will help you to understand QGraphicsScene coordinate system!

P.S.:

```
QGraphicsRectItem* pRect1 = pScene->addRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
QGraphicsRectItem* pRect2 = pScene->addRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
pRect1->setPos(QPoint(40,40));
pRect2->setPos(QPoint(20,20));
```